# Regex: negative look-ahead with text afterwards

Tags: regex

I can't see why the following doesn't work for me.

I need to match:

```
ListenAddress <any IP>
```

This appears to do the job:

```
^ListenAddress (?!10\.1\.41\.16)
```

That will match any IP except `10.1.41.16`, but it also matches

```
10.1.41.167
```

Which I need it to **not** match.

Comment: Maybe `^ListenAddress (?!10.1.41.16\b)`

Comment: also you should have `\.` in place of `.`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match only `16 or 167`  this regex `10\.1\.41\.16(7|)\b`  is suitable for your case.

If you need to match any number after 16 this one `10\.1\.41\.16(|[0-9])\b` will be suitable in this case.

This  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9RqRfp/1) explains the answer.

Comment: Thanks, \b was the option I was needing.

Comment: great, if this helps, would you like to accept the answer